# Conditionally change displayed value of a list in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have an array that is outputted and displayed using ng-repeat, with the list and example data being as follows:

List display:

```
<li ng-repeat="ingredients in recipeObject.ingredients">
                            {{ ingredients.amount + ' ' + ingredients.unit + ' '+ ingredients.ingredient}}
                        </li>
```

Example object:

```
$scope.recipeObject = {
        ingredients : [
            {amount:1, unit:"tablespoon", ingredient:"Olive oil"},
            {amount:0.5, unit:"", ingredient:"Red onion"},
            {amount:2 , unit:"", ingredient:"Bay leaves"}]
}
```

Which will display something that looks like

[image]

However, I would like to be able to replace values such as 0.5 with values such as "Half", so the displayed value would read something like "Half a Red onion".

I do not want to change the amount to the string, as the amount being numeric allows me to compute important data.

Is there a way to conditionally change the displayed amount, such as if the amount is a decimal value, to a different format?
Alternatively, having a display filter that changes the decimal value to a fraction is acceptable too.

Comment: OK. Now what is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to conditionally change the value displayed to the user if it satisfies certain criteria, such as being a decimal value.

Comment: Yes, of course, using a filter for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Best (scalable/angular-ish) - filter (as mentioned above)
2. Ugly:

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="ingredients in recipeObject.ingredients">
     {{ 
       ingredients.amount==0.5?'half':
       ingredients.amount==0.25?'quarter':
       //etc...
       ingredients.amount
       + ' ' + ingredients.unit + ' '+ ingredients.ingredient}}
   </li>
   ```
3. Easy

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="ingredients in recipeObject.ingredients">
     {{ myFormat(ingredients.amount) + ' ' + ingredients.unit + ' '+ ingredients.ingredient}}
   </li>
   ```

   And inside controller:

   ```
   $scope.myFormat = function(input){
     if (input == 0.5) return 'half';
     else if (input == 0.25) return 'quarter';
     //etc...
     else return input
   }
   ```